# How to validate enums in yup

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, yup

I'm using yup to create validations for my data , how can i handle enums?

this is a sample of my validations - I'm using object.shape method of the yup:

```
export const deleteCityValidation = yup.object().shape({
  id: yup.string()
});
```

looking for a way to validate an input field that should only have a value from a set of enums any help is appreciated .

is it possible to use yup.arrays to validate enums ?

Comment: Looking at the docs something like: `yup.mixed<keyof typeof YOUR_ENUM>().oneOf(Object.values(YOUR_ENUM))` could work.

Comment: @r3dst0rm thanks for the comment i think that might fix the problem but i should test it , I'm really sorry to ask such a stupid question but whats that  ```< keyof typeof > ``` thing called? i mean the whole thing inside these < >

Comment: An enum is under the hood nothing more than an object, with typeof you let TypeScript infer a type and with keyof we can get all valid indices of that object as a type. Since `mixed` is a generic function which needs a type definition, we put such a type inside those `< >` brackets.

Answer (score 37):

you can use example like below:

```
let schema = yup.mixed().oneOf(['jimmy', 42]);

await schema.isValid(42); // => true
await schema.isValid('jimmy'); // => true
await schema.isValid(new Date()); // => false
```

more [info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#mixedoneofarrayofvalues-arrayany-message-string--function-schema-alias-equals)

Comment: Or he can use regEx depending on the type of the variable: 

`let schema = string().matches(/(jimmy|test)/);`

Answer (score 32):

The code below works for your example:

```
  field: yup.mixed<EnumName>().oneOf(Object.values(EnumName))
    .required(),
```

Comment: yup.mixed<EnumName>().oneOf(Object.values(EnumName))
    .required()

Comment: @AminDarian you are right, the way the way yup was imported in the question it should be ‚yup.mix…‘. I adapted the answer

Comment: Got an error here when passing the Object.values(MyEnum) as an argument to oneOf (I'm using Typescript):
Argument of type '(string | MyEnum)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly (Reference<unknown> | MyEnum| undefined)[]'

Comment: @JoelLopes shouldn‘t be your Enum be of type Enum only and not type Enum | String. The above answer should work fine with TypeScript for sure, since I also used TypeScript back then.