# YUP NODE JS flat dictionary object validation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, yup

I have a form data like this

```
labels: { 'EN-US': 'foo bar', 'EN-BR': 'foo baz' }
```

How to validate it through YUP? where there are no names for the Object while I searched a lot to create object names through HTML without Js m But I did not find a way, So I have to send them flat, but there is really no reference to validate such dictionary object?

I want only the schema structure for both keys and values and I will do the rest .. consider I need them Just strings?

Comment: Does this help? validate them as enums . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836052/how-to-validate-enums-in-yup

Comment: not too much… for me